# Microphone not working with headset jack splitter

Tags: windows-10, microphone, headset, splitter, headphone-jack

I am trying to connect my headset to my computer and I am having problems with the microphone.
My headset is a [Sennheiser MOMENTUM 2](https://en-cn.sennheiser.com/momentum-m2), which has a 4 pole jack. My computer has separate connectors for headphones and microphone, so I purchased [this splitter cable](https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B073ZDDTH2/) and connected everything.

The headphones work correctly, but not the microphone. When I check the sound properties on Windows, there's a "Test your microphone" section with a volume bar. If I speak I don't see any indication of sound, but it I blow into the microphone, the bar moves, showing that at least something is happening.

[image: Mic level indicator]

I've checked the connection from the splitter cable to the motherboard and everything seems correct. The left and right poles go to the left and right pins of the MB, respectively. The ground goes to the ground pin, and the microphone pole goes to both left and right microphone pins.

I tried going to the microphone device properties on Windows and increase both the volume and the boost to their maximum settings, but that did not seem to have any effect.

[image: Microphone properties]

I've tested the headset with my phone and they work as expected, and I also tried using my phone's headset on my PC but the result was the same.

**At this point I am not sure what else to try. The connection appears to be correct, and I can see some activity on the microfone by blowing into it. Why doesn't it work?**

Comment: Suggestion: try swapping equipment.  Have you tried connecting any other microphone (or audio input source) into the adapter?  (It could be that the adapter is broken, or is designed for some different equipment standard and so just it might just not work as expected.  In that case, no software settings are likely to remedy this.)

Comment: I thought about it but I don't have any standalone microphone around. This is a standard motherboard, so I don't think it is designed for specialized equipment.

Comment: Left and right microphone? Are there two microphones? Or did you mistake microphone negative/positive for microphone left/right?

Comment: I notice there are in-wire controls on the headset. wondering if this is a potential source of problems: i think the buttons signal using variable resistance on the microphone signal. e.g. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/242883/how-do-media-buttons-on-a-plain-wired-headset-work/242884

Comment: @svin83 My motherboard's manual indicates that the pins are "MIC L" and "MIC R", respectively. I think that implies that a stereo microphone could be used.

Comment: @Yorik According to that schematic, these should not have any effect unless pressed. When I press the buttons, I can see a spike in the microphone volume monitor, but if I don't press them I think they should not have any effect.

Comment: but the headset only has one microphone?

Comment: Yes, it has only one. I suppose that being connected to both left and right channels would just cause the same sound to be captured on both channels, but I may be mistaken. However, this splitting seems fairly standard.

Answer (score 1):

There are **2 main standards** for 4-pole audio connectors: **OMTP** and **CTIA**.

The 4-pole connector is often called as **Tip-Ring-Ring-Sleeve** (TRRS for short). The standards define TRRS for audio connectors differently:

- OMTP defines TRRS as **Left-Right-Mic-Ground**
- CTIA defines TRRS as **Left-Right-Ground-Mic**

The Y-splitter you've referenced uses CTIA standard. But I couldn't find if it's the same for Sennheiser Momentum 2.

If you use wrong connectors you end up with working audio but with not working or purely working microphone.

You may buy a convertor from one standard to another, though.

You may also check what standards are in your computer. They may differ too.

P.S. I have a Syncwire Y-splitter which has CTIA headphone connector and OMTP mic connector. It's a mistake, I'm convinced. The mic didn't work but I could fix it with a CTIA-OMTP converter.